# Why does spring websocket application not see html and throws a 404 error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, websocket

I'm trying to make a chat using spring boot and websocket according to the guide.

Simple config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class webSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

my controller :

```
@Controller
public class MessageController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/chatting")
    public Message messageHandler(Name name) throws Exception{
        return new Message("Hello, " + name.getName() + " !");
    }
}
```

class for message:

```
public class Message {
    private String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Message(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Message() {

    }
}
```

and class for name:

```
package com.example.webSocketChat.Messages;

public class Name {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Name() {

    }
}
```

And actually the html page itself, it is located in **resource/static**,although for some reason there was no static folder, although I created the project through Spring Initializr:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello WebSocket</title>
    <script src="sockjs-0.3.4.js"></script>
    <script src="stomp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var stompClient = null;

        function setConnected(connected) {
            document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
            document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
            document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
        }

        function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS('/chat');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/chatting', function(message){
                    showGreeting(JSON.parse(message.body).content);
                });
            });
        }

        function disconnect() {
            stompClient.disconnect();
            setConnected(false);
            console.log("Disconnected");
        }

        function sendName() {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
        }

        function showGreeting(message) {
            var response = document.getElementById('response');
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
            p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
            response.appendChild(p);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><h2 style="color: #ff0000">Seems your browser doesn't support Javascript! Websocket relies on Javascript being enabled. Please enable
    Javascript and reload this page!</h2></noscript>
<div>
    <div>
        <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
        <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">Disconnect</button>
    </div>
    <div id="conversationDiv">
        <label>What is your name?</label><input type="text" id="name" />
        <button id="sendName" onclick="sendName();">Send</button>
        <p id="response"></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems to have done everything correctly according to the guide and figured out what was going on, but if you go to the address at startup **http://localhost:8080** it throws a 404 error but if you go to the address **http://localhost:8080/chat** will be the message **Welcome to SockJS!**.

What could be the mistake here? I can't notice it, I did everything according to 2 guides and there is exactly the same code. I will be glad to help

Comment: Share your code on github.

Comment: @AnishB. https://github.com/ShanksRed/webSocketChat

Comment: ok let me check.

Comment: I'm getting 404. Now, what is the requirement

Comment: @AnishB. well, in theory, you should get a page with the name input and buttons

Comment: ok just wait. let me check.

Comment: Got the issue. I have fixed. Adding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so could you please clarify the problem?
Is it why the page is showing 404 error at root url but the /chat route works?

If you are asking the above then check the HTML file where under `connect()` you are **opening the socket at “/chat” route**.
Also in your **Java code the endpoint is under /chat**, hence that triggers the SockJS connection. The root url doesn’t do anything.